# Entity Framework modifying collection property with detect changes off

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For performance reasons I have AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false on the DbContext.

Updating simple properties and reference properties all works fine but I am having trouble with collection properties that are many-to-many and don't have a joining class.

This is abbreviated code trying to add to the collection:

```
var item = context.Set<Item>().FirstOrDefault();    
var category = context.Set<Category>().FirstDefault();

context.Entry(item).Collection(i => i.Categories).CurrentValue.Add(category);
```

But it does nothing, after SaveChanges the database is same as it was. Is this the correct way to be doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Call:

```
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

Or:

```
context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: `context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;` doesn't affect navigation properties, so that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought that EF executed `DetectChanges` as part of `SaveChanges` *no matter what*. But inspecting the source code reveals that even then `DetectChanges` isn't executed when `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `false`.

I think in your case, the best you can do is override `SaveChanges` so it will always detect changes before saving:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var detectChanges = this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;
    try
    {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = detectChanges;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` in the override, but by setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true`, EF itself  will choose the moment when to call `DetectChanges` during `SaveChanges`, which seems preferable to me.